# How do you indicate whether the supply of power to the gyroscopic instruments is adequate?

Tags: aircraft-systems, avionics

Is there an instrument to indicate this?

Comment: What type of aircraft are you interested in? The instrumentation of a new airliner is different from a glider, or a 1930's biplane.

Comment: @DanHulme Would like to know what the commercial plane use

Comment: All the types of aircraft I mentioned are flown commercially. Are you asking specifically about airliners?

Answer (score 2):

For suction powered gyroscopic instruments there is usually some suction gauge to indicate the quality of the vacuum. See [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12558/what-does-the-suction-gauge-actually-show) for more details in what the instrument shows.